# How to use SQL in the most efficient way with very big tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table `purchase`
something like (`id`, `buyer_id`, `seller_id`, `amount`) with 20-30 millions of records
Also i have a table with the same structure `purchase_archive`
and table `users_balance` (`id`, `user_id`, `balance`)

I should write a script that:

1. Moves records from `purchase` to `purchase_archive` table
2. For each moved row `users_balance` should be updated (user balance should be decreased for `amount` if he is a buyer, and increased for the same amount if he is a seller)

What is the best way to solve this task? (PHP + Mysql PDO)

My assumption is:

1. Set table engine to InnoDB
2. SELECT batch of 1000 rows from first table
3. Begin transaction (thats the reason for the InnoDB)
4. For each row

   4.1 Store id in array ($temp)

   4.2 Update balance with query like

   ```
   SELECT `amount` FROM `purchase` WHERE `id` = :tid LIMIT 1 INTO @amount;
   UPDATE `users_balance` SET `balance` = CASE 
   WHEN `user_id` = :seller_id THEN `balance` + @amount 
   WHEN `user_id` = :buyer_id THEN `balance` - @amount END 
   WHERE `user_id` IN (:buyer_id, :seller_id);
   ```
5. Move rows into archive with the query like that:

   ```
       INSERT INTO `purchase_archive` SELECT * FROM `purchase` WHERE `id` IN (".$temp.");
       DELETE QUICK FROM `transactions` WHERE `id` IN (".$temp.");
   ```
6. End transaction

And repeat 2-6 in cycle.

The longest operation is point 4.2, and i dont know how to perform it faster without variables

Is there any faster approaches?

P.S. Sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: is `purchase` really spelled incorrectly all the way through? also you may want to just consider partitioning the table by purchase date and forgoing the notion of archiving them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I made mistake in `purchase` for the first time and then copy-paste it through all document, excuse me for that. Now i cannot divide this table because of couple of reasons, and i have to work with that structure. In fact, I want to know if there any faster SQL query for that task.

Comment: partitioning wouldnt change your table in any way that would require application level changes. but anyway, you can do what you wish in a single query, without looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
update user_balance b 
  inner join (
    select b.user_id, 
           sum(case when p.buyer_id = b.user_id then p.amount else 0 end) bought, 
           sum(case when p.seller_id = b.user_id then p.amount else 0 end) sold
    from purchase p 
      inner join user_balance b 
        on p.buyer_id = b.user_id 
          or p.seller_id = b.user_id 
    group by b.user_id) q 
    on b.user_id = q.user_id 
    set b.amount = b.amount + q.sold - q.bought;
```

And it should do everything in a single query.  You can limit the range further in the inner query if you wish. SQL Fiddle seems to be down so I can't provide a live demo, but there is this:

```
mysql> select * from user_balance;
+---------+--------+
| user_id | amount |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |     50 |
|       2 |     50 |
|       3 |     50 |
|       4 |     50 |
+---------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from purchase;
+-------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| purchase_id | seller_id | buyer_id | amount |
+-------------+-----------+----------+--------+
|           1 |         1 |        2 |     10 |
|           2 |         3 |        4 |     20 |
|           3 |         4 |        2 |      5 |
|           4 |         1 |        4 |      7 |
|           5 |         3 |        1 |      9 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and after the query....

```
mysql> update user_balance b inner join (select b.user_id, sum(case when p.buyer_id = b.user_id then p.amount else 0 end) bought, sum(case when p.seller_id = b.user_id then p.amount else 0 end) sold from purchase p inner join user_balance b on p.buyer_id = b.user_id or p.seller_id = b.user_id group by b.user_id) q on b.user_id = q.user_id set b.amount = b.amount + q.sold - q.bought;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from user_balance;
+---------+--------+
| user_id | amount |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |     58 |
|       2 |     35 |
|       3 |     79 |
|       4 |     28 |
+---------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks. This query is correct, but it is very slow on real table (because of Sum and Group by on table with 22kk rows), and we dont have enough memory to run this universal query

Comment: Are you archiving the entire table or just a subset?

Comment: And are seller and buyer ids indexed? If so it may be faster to do them separately

Comment: I should archive a subset of this table (~10kk rows) (there is one more column in real table, which determine if this row should be archived), but it is big enough. Seller and Buyer are indexed columns. Ill try to process them separately asap and write result

Comment: @СергейРусаков how did you go?

Comment: I could not check solution on sunday. Today I tried both variants, and unfortunately found no much differents in speed between my and your variants. I understand that in some cases your variant will be much more better, but my is not the one. Nevertheless, thank you! You helped me a lot in understanding how to construct complex queries and how they works!